# Toplink foreign key with value zero

Tags: java, junit, oracle11g, foreign-key-relationship, toplink

I’m modernizing an application which uses an Oracle 11g DB with Toplink.

I’m having a problem with foreign keys which are ints of value zero.

The application is kind of complicated so I have created a simple project with a two table DB, Toplink configured in the same way as the app and some JUnit tests to drive some simple requests through to the DB. One table (Party) has a reference to the other table (Address). An address can be used by many Party. It’s mapped as one-to-many in the Toplink Workbench

Everything works fine until I try to create or update a Party referencing an Address with id zero. This throws a Toplink exception.

**NB.** It’s no problem creating an Address with id zero, and it’s no problem creating or updating a Party with an Address of greater than zero.

Here is the exception I see on the create:

```
    [TopLink Warning]: 2014.01.22 11:51:26.333--UnitOfWork(76409034)--        Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink - 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.6.0) (Build 111018)): oracle.toplink.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (PARTIES.ADR_PK) violated

    Error Code: 1
    Call: INSERT INTO PTY_ADDRESS (ADR_ID, ADR_STREET, ADR_COUNTRY, ADR_NAME, ADR_CITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        bind => [0, street, country, venue, city]
    Query: InsertObjectQuery(ch.hp.parties.Address@2e931d05)
```

Any ideas?

John D.

Comment: Did you check if you actually have an address with id 0??

Comment: Yes, certainly. I have JUnit tests driving all the cases. And you can be sure I've been backwards and forwards over this many times. :-)